# rename Model Name from find('all') with cakePHP 2.X

Tags: php, cakephp, model, find

I have a Model Order.

When I do `find('all')` in my table Order, cakephp return data like this:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Order' => array(
            'id' => '10'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Order' => array(
            'id' => '11'
        )
    )
)
```

Is there any way for rename 'Order' into 'myTEST' ?

Comment: Short of iterating over the contents and rewriting them? I don't believe so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Order` model you could possibly implement an `afterFind` callback to replace `[Order]` with `[myTEST]`. Something like this might work for you:

```
public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    $new_results = array();

    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        foreach($val as $v){
            $new_results[$key]['myTEST'] = $v;
        }
    }

    return $new_results;

    // OR you could also take this approach - Less coding and perhaps more efficient

    // foreach ($results as $key => $val){
    //   $results[$key]['myTEST'] = $results[$key]['Order'];
    //   unset($results[$key]['Order']);
    // }

    // return $results;
}
```

I have not tested this at all.